# Manga where a female office worker finds a slime and takes it home

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can’t for the life of me find this manga about a female office worker who find this slime monster that can change forms(?). She takes him home and they form a relationship.

I think it might have been something like the more they sleep together the prettier she gets(?)

<sub>n.b. It's not *The Time I Got Reincarnated As A Slime*</sub>

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You mention sleeping together - was this pornographic or (mostly) work safe? Was it a manga with multiple chapters, or just a oneshot?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and searched for it for like an hour. Just now I tried searching "squishy" and BINGO!

It's "My Special Squishy Someone". From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/52742738):

> After losing all hope of finding love, Ha-eun doesn't see the point of carrying on...until one day, a mysterious being saves her life and promises to make her irresistible to any man. Its method is unorthodox to say the least, but it sure makes her feel good.